# com.user.loginscript[ ]): Exited with code: 1

Tags: macos, terminal, launchctl

Whenever we restart our server it changes our DNS and apache settings. I haven't been able to figure out why, so I wrote a quick script to restore these to safe settings on login to fix Mac OS X Server's presumptuousness.

So I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                 
cp /Users/takp/Safe/apachesites/*.* /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites
cp /Users/takp/Safe/named/*.*  /Library/Server/named
apachectl restart
```

And added a launchctl plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Users/takp/Safe/loginscript.sh</string>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And made it executable

But whenever I try to run it I get the error:

```
com.user.loginscript[87776]): Exited with code: 1
```

How can I get this login script to run happily?

Comment: What version of OSX?

Comment: Sorry - 10.9.2 all software updates applied.